# jQuery focus on one element, then another immediately after

Tags: jquery, focus

I'm trying to set focus on one element, then immediately set it back to the previously focused item. Here's the HTML:

```
<input id="em3" type="email" />
<p class="error" tabindex="0">Please fill out the email field</p>
```

I've tried this:

```
$(this).next('.error').focus();
$(this).prev('input').focus();
```

and this:

```
$(this).next('.error').focus();
setTimeout(function(){
      $(this).prev('input').focus();
}, 2000);
```

But neither works. The focus stays on the ".error" element.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which element is `this` when you run the code? Changing focus to the next element doesn't change `this`. So if you started at the `input` and want to go back to it, it should just be `$(this).focus()`.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is:**

> It's because `$(this)` in the setTimeout handler is referring to
>   window, which is presumably not the same value as referenced by
>   `$(this)` outside the handler. so You need to assign your `$(this)` in
>   the outer scope

```
var ThisIt = $(this);
ThisIt.next('.error').focus();
setTimeout(function(){
      ThisIt.focus();
}, 2000);
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#em3').on('click',function(){
    var ThisIt = $(this);
    ThisIt.next('.error').focus();
    setTimeout(function(){
      ThisIt.focus();
    }, 2000); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="em3" type="email" />
<p class="error" tabindex="0">Please fill out the email field</p>
```

> **Note: *1st:*** click on the input to see the action .. ***2nd:*** as @Barmar said in comment .. no need to use `prev()` .

Comment: Thanks guys. Doesn't work when you have pair of inputs and errors on the page though, it gets stuck in a loop. Hence the "next". More context:

$('input, select, textarea').blur( function(e)
{
    if( !$(this).val() ) {
          $(this).next('.error').css('display', 'inline');
   var ThisIt = $(this);
    ThisIt.next('.error').focus();
    setTimeout(function(){
      ThisIt.focus();
    }, 2000); 
    }
 
 else {
          $(this).next('.error').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).closest('li').next('li').find('*').focus();
    }
});